# Get the closest value of a number from an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
["7", "8", "11", "13", "14"]
```

I want the closest inferior number to `11` if any (i.e., `8`), or if such a number does not exist, then the closest superior number to `11` (i.e., `13`).

Comment: When implementing the method you described, what happened? Did you get any errors or wrong results? Please describe your approach and any errors you got. Please also see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details about how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. What is "closest number"? By index, by value? Be more specific and you always can use [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html)

Comment: A few more details would help. Is the array sorted? Are you permitted to have duplicates? Is your array of ints actually defined as an array of Strings? What if the array is empty? What are the constraints on the passed in integer? Examples with input and output covering these cases will help us help you.

Comment: @miss.serena None of your questions (except "What if the array is empty?") makes a point. If not sorted, then just sort it. I don't get why duplicates matter. As the OP gave, they are clearly strings. Why do you need a constraint on the integers?

Answer (score 26):

Try the below shortest method for getting the closest value:

```
n = 40
a = [20, 30, 45, 50, 56, 60, 64, 80]
a.min_by{|x| (n-x).abs}
```

Comment: why we need sort here? without sort its working fine.

Comment: The problem is not to obtain the closest value; it is to obtain the closest value no greater than `n` if there are any values that do not exceed `n`, else the closest value that is greater than `n`.

Comment: This is a good solution to a *different* question. The expected result in the above example was supposed to be `30`, not `45`.

Answer (score 16):

```
h = ["7", "8", "11", "13", "14"].map(&:to_i).sort.group_by{|e| e <=> 11}
h[-1].last || h[1].first # => 8
```

Comment: For people like me that were looking at "I want the closest lowest number to  3 in an array, with exact match if possible", here is your solution: 
`tmp = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6].sort.group_by {|e| e <=> number_to_find}; closest_or_exact_number = tmp.try(:[], 0).first || tmp.try(:[], -1).last || tmp[1].first`

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way to solve this:

```
a = arr.map(&:to_i).sort      #=> [7, 8, 11, 13, 14]
a.reverse.find { |e| e < 11 } #=> 8
a.find { |e| e > 11 }         #=> 13
```

Since [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) returns `nil` if no object matches, the last two lines can be combined via:

```
a.reverse.find { |e| e < 11 } || a.find { |e| e > 11 }
```

Comment: ...or `a.reverse_each.find ..` to avoid the creation of the temporary array `a.reverse`.

Answer (score 5):

The following method, which does not sort the array, has a time-complexity of O(n), n being the size of the array. By contrast, for methods that sort the array as a first step, the time-complexity is at best O(nlog(n)). [Ref](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/quicksort-the-best-sorting-algorithm-6ab461b5a9d0)

To avoid obscuring the central element of the question, I will assume that the array contains integers rather than string representations of integers. I will briefly address this point after presenting the solution.

```
def closest(arr, target)
  return nil if arr.empty?
  arr.min_by  { |e| e <= target ? [0, target-e] : [1, e-target] }
end
```

```
arr = [11, 7, 13, 8, 11, 14]
```

```
closest(arr, 12)   #=> 11
closest(arr, 12.5) #=> 11
closest(arr, 11)   #=> 11
closest(arr, 4)    #=>  7
closest(arr, 7)    #=>  7
```

See [Enumerable#min_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by).

Note that arrays are ordered by the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (see the document's third paragraph), so, for example,

```
target = 12
arr.sort_by  { |e| e <= target ? [0, target-e] : [1, e-target] }
  #=> [11, 11, 8, 7, 13, 14]
```

Because `0 < 1`, the four elements that are no larger than `target` make up the first four elements of the array returned (`[11, 11, 8, 7]`) and the two elements that are greater than `target` comprise the last two elements (`[13, 14]`), both groups being ordered by the "distance" to `target`. The method does not use `sort_by`, but it orders the elements of `arr` the same way.

`[0, target-e]` and `[1, e-target]` could replaced by `[n1, target-e]` and `[n2, e-target]`, where `n1` and `n2` are any objects for which `n1 <=> n2 #=> -1`. For example, `n1 = -7` and `n2 = 42` or `n1 = 'a'` and `n2 = 'b'`.

---

If `arr` contains strings representations of integers, as in the question, one may either convert the array to an array of integers as a first step or change the method as follows.

```
def closest(arr, target)
  return nil if arr.empty?
  target_f = target.to_f
  arr.min_by do |e|
    e_f = e.to_f
    e_f <= target_f ? [0, target_f-e_f] : [1, e_f-target_f]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using a combination of `take_while` and `drop_while`:

Assuming the array is already sorted, this only iterates through the array exactly as far as it needs to and no further:

```
arr.take_while {|x| x.to_i < num}.last || arr.drop_while {|x| x.to_i<=num}.first
```

And here it is inserted into a defined method for clarity and testing:

```
arr_1 = ["7", "9", "11", "13", "14"]
arr_2 = ["11", "13", "14"]
arr_3 = ["13", "14"]
arr_4 = ["11"]
arr_5 = []
arr_6 = ["-2", "-1", "11", "12"]

def first_closest(number, sorted_string_array)
  arr = sorted_string_array
  num = number
  arr.take_while {|x| x.to_i < num}.last || arr.drop_while {|x| x.to_i<=num}.first
end

first_closest(11, arr_1)
#=>  9
first_closest(11, arr_2)
#=>  13
first_closest(11, arr_3)
#=>  13
first_closest(11, arr_4)
#=>  nil
first_closest(11, arr_5)
#=>  nil
first_closest(11, arr_6)
#=>  -1
```